# SessionRegistry returns an empty list of authenticated users

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an event listener, which when it receive the event that the user has changed their password invalidates the session. This is the code:

```
@Component
public class UserListener {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    @EventListener
    public void handleChangePasswordEvent(ChangePasswordEvent event) {
        logger.info("handleChangePasswordEvent for : " + event.getUsername());
        List<Object> loggedUsers = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
        logger.info("loggedUsers : " + loggedUsers.size());
        for (Object principal : loggedUsers) {
            if (principal instanceof User) {
                final User loggedUser = (User) principal;
                logger.info("loggedUser : " + loggedUser.getUsername());
                if (event.getUsername().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())) {
                    List<SessionInformation> sessionsInfo = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false);
                    if (null != sessionsInfo && sessionsInfo.size() > 0) {
                        for (SessionInformation sessionInformation : sessionsInfo) {
                            logger.info("Exprire now :" + sessionInformation.getSessionId());
                            sessionInformation.expireNow();
                            sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessionInformation.getSessionId());
                            // User is not forced to re-logging
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The listener works fine, the problem is that the list of authenticated users that returns me sessionRegistry is empty.

I've tried all the solutions I've seen for the same problem and they have not worked for me.

Here I put all the configuration of Spring Security.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(value = { "security" })
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomLogoutHandler logoutHandler;


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .authenticationEventPublisher(authenticationEventPublisher())
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher() {
        return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher();
    }


    /**
     * Security Configuration for Admin zone
     */
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class AdminConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasAuthority(AuthorityEnum.ROLE_ADMIN.name())
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/admin/login")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .successHandler(successHandler)
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/login?logout")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Security Configuration for Frontend zone
     */
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class FrontendConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*.*")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()
                .csrf();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public class GlobalWebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

        @Autowired
        private MessageSource messageSource;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.sessionManagement()
                    .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy())
                    .sessionFixation()
                    .changeSessionId()
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                    .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                    .and()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/");

            // Here we protect site from:
            // 1. X-Content-Type-Options
            http.headers().contentTypeOptions();
            // 2. Web Browser XSS Protection
            http.headers().xssProtection();
            http.headers().cacheControl();
            http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity();
            // 3. X-Frame-Options
            http.headers().frameOptions();

        }

        @Bean
        public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
            if (sessionRegistry == null) {
                sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
            }
            return sessionRegistry;
        }

        @Bean
        @Order(1)
        public ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy() {
            ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy strategy = new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
            strategy.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(true);
            strategy.setMessageSource(messageSource);
            return strategy;
        }

        @Bean
        @Order(2)
        public SessionFixationProtectionStrategy sessionFixationProtectionStrategy(){
            return new SessionFixationProtectionStrategy();
        }

        @Bean
        @Order(3)
        public RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy(){
            RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy = new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
            return registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
        }

        @Bean
        public CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(){
            List<SessionAuthenticationStrategy> sessionAuthenticationStrategies = new ArrayList<>();
            sessionAuthenticationStrategies.add(concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy());
            sessionAuthenticationStrategies.add(sessionFixationProtectionStrategy());
            sessionAuthenticationStrategies.add(registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy());
            CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy = new CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategies);
            return compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
        }

    }
}
```

I have a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for the admin zone with its own login page and another for normal users.

At the end is  **GlobalWebConfiguration** to configure the session manager for both zones (admin and users).

Hope someone can help me

Comment: Are there many ways (locations in code) to change the password? If not why not just call session.invalidate() directly after the password is successfully changed. The event+listener concept is much harder to read, because it put distance between the source of the event and the action to be performed, so I would only use it if I had multiple location where the password could be changed, and/or a substantial amount of code that would be duplicated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in principle I have two controllers to change the password of a user, one in the admin zone and another in the users zone. The event + listener approach I found very interesting to decouple code and avoid injecting the HttpServletRequest. But you're right, it may introduce unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Anyway I would like to know why the sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals () returns me an empty listing.

Comment: If you would like to know, then you will probably have to debug it (which should be fairly easy). Another question is, why do you want to log the user out? Typically we just update the user authentication using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication() directly.